# How to select an option with fireevent “on change” using VBA

Tags: javascript, html, vba

I'm a real beginner, so sorry for the rubbish syntax.

I'm trying to select (click) an option (with "onchange") and I can't (I've tried many things over a month, and nothing worked). I've tried to declare obj as a iHtmlFormElement / SelectionElement - nothing worked.

Thanks for the help!

My code until now:

```
Sub PL()

Dim DOC As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim obj As Object

Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "link"

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

Set DOC = IE.document

DOC.getElementById("txtUsername").Value = "user"
DOC.getElementById("USMPWD").Value = "pass"
DOC.getElementById("BTNSUB").click

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

Set DOC = IE.document
Set obj = DOC.getElementsByTagName("listBox")

???here I'm stuck


End Sub
```

---

The html code:

```
<select name="listBox" id="listBox" style="width: 240px;" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'listBox\',\'\')', 0)" size="18">
    <option value="1">20</option>
    <option value="2">30</option>
    <option value="3">50</option>
    <option value="5">51</option>
    <option value="4">60</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Should be `Set obj = DOC.getElementsByTagName("listBox")(0)` since that methods returns a collection, not a single item.  It's always useful to show a few of the things that you tried, and describe what happened when you tried them.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I've spent hours before posting this msg (as a last resort). I've actually tried Set obj = DOC.getElementsByTagName("listBox")(0). The problem was the selection part the comes afterward..

Comment: `Set obj = DOC.getElementsByTagName("select")(0)` sorry I missed the tagname part earlier.  Or you can use `Set obj = DOC.getElementById("listBox")`   When you have a reference to the select you can set its `selectedIndex` to pick a specific value.

Comment: I've tried (obj decalred as HtmlFormElement): `Set obj = DOC.getElementById("listBox")`
`obj.selectedIndex = 1` ,and I get error 91 - "object varialble or with block variable not set" on this line=> `obj.selectedIndex = 1`

Comment: With no URL to use for testing I can't really suggest anything else.  If getElementById is failing, that's telling you there's no element with that Id on the page when your script runs.  You could try introducing a short Wait in case the select is loaded dynamically after the main page completes.

Comment: Doc.querySelector("#listBox [value='1']").Selected = True. Change one to 2,3,5,4 depending on desires option

Answer (score 0):

Below "Set DOC = IE.document":

```
'Your target object has a name="listBox" and an id="listBox", but your TagName is "select". Adjust accordingly.
Set obj = DOC.getElementById("listBox")
'Your value ranges from 1 to 5. Don't pay attention to the real numbers shown in your page.
obj.value = "1"
'Let's fire the "onchange" event like pros!
DOC.parentWindow.execscript "javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'listBox\',\'\')', 0)"
```

And that's it. Of course you can complicate this.